# Reading text file from terminal line?

Tags: c, string, algorithm

So I understand that to read and print out a line of text you can just use `printf`, `scanf` and type it out. However what if I want to print out a text file without typing them out in terminal? And I don't mean using `fopen(filename, "r")` where you can only open a specific file. I think this is called redirection but I'm having trouble understanding it. Something along the line as the below input example:

```
./myprogram < input.txt
```

Comment: Do you mean that every time your program asks for input, it will get it from the "input.txt" file?

Comment: not specifically that file but whatever is after the "<"

Comment: Not sure if I understand you, you want to read whatever is at the right of the < sign? if so, you can use fread to read from stdin.

Comment: @stylo yes that is correct but how?

Comment: in the fread function, the last argument is the stream you're specifying, just call it with fread(your_buffer, buffer_size, 1, stdin);

Comment: You can still just use `scanf` to read from files.

Comment: Oh what I thought `scanf` is only for keyboard input

Comment: `scanf` reads from whatever `stdin` is connected to. In fact, you shouldn't use it for user input.

Comment: Ok Ive figured it out, thanks for helping me out guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [redirection cheat sheet](https://catonmat.net/ftp/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf). The line that interest us is:

> `cmd < file`:  Redirect the contents of the file to the standard input (stdin) of cmd.

Here a simple example that will print the content of your `input.txt` file. Compared to manual input, the program will never wait and will loop until the end of the file is reached (*Note: there are cases where there is no end, you might want to add alternative break condition*).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char    buffer[100];

    while (fgets(buffer, 100, stdin))
        printf("%s", buffer);
    return (0);
}
```

- `./myprogram < input.txt` will print your input.txt
- `./myprogram` will wait for your manual input and print what you just typed.

Comment: yeah Ive tried that but for some reason its not printing any of the lines out, when I did it without the while loop i.e only `fgets(buffer, 100, stdin)`, it only prints out the first line of the text file

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked but you can put the filename as argument and get it in argv[1] and then use fopen

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what they're asking.

Comment: yes because he doesn't want to have a fixed filename but using argv resolves the problem

Comment: Re-reading the question I'm even more confused. I mean, you're not wrong if they're asking how they can open a file passed from the command line. But it's not clear to me that that's what they're asking. They threw input redirection into the mix and I have to wonder if they're asking about that instead.